# HQL right join empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I am using hql with hibernate. I've tried to write a query over three tables. The tables are Medientyp, RaumMedientyp and Raum. I wanna read all Medientyp's from the whole table and all RaumMedientyp's from a specific raumId.
The realtions between the tables are:
**`Medientyp` 1 <--> mc `RaumMedientyp` mc <--> 1 `Raum`**
I need all as RaumMedientyp Entity.
The query i tried is:

```
String hql = "from RaumMedientyp rm right join rm.medientyp m inner join rm.raum r where r.id = :raumId";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setInteger(":raumId", raumId);
```

But if i'm executing

```
query.list();
```

i've got a empty list as return.

Comment: why you join medientyp?

Comment: I don't really see the point in joining `rm.medientyp` or is RaumMedienTyp some `n:m`-table?

Comment: no it's a m to 1 and i use the right join because i wanna have all medientyps and if it have no raummedientyp then create a new raummedientyp with only the medientyp object as attribut